Scaling by axis causing model to deform
I'm trying to shrink the cylinder via the G+Zhotkeys but it repeatedly causes the vertices to snap backward to the plane.
How do I fix this?


Hello you have enabled the Snap option, is it what you want?

It's also on the Snap to Face option (square icon in the top toolbar next to the hilighted magnet icon) so the vertices will snap to the plane.
